# spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

Tags: doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

i have a productRepositiry model which is used to create a product in the database

```
class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository{
public function createProduct($productDetails) {
     $this->_em->persist($productDetails);
     $this->_em->flush();
     log_message("info","Product {$productDetails->name} created.");
     print "Product {$productDetails->name} created.<br/><br/><br/>";
     return $productDetails;
}
```

procuct controller, this get the value using post and passes the values to the productRepositiry

```
public function addProduct(){
    if(! $this->session->userdata('user_id')){
        redirect('welcome');
    }else{
        $productDetails = new Entity\Product;
        $productDetails->market = $this->input->post('mid');
        $productDetails->name =  $this->input->post('product_name');
        $productDetails->price =  $this->input->post('product_price');
        $productDetails->discount =  $this->input->post('product_discount');
        $productDetails->category =  $this->input->post('product_cat');
        $productDetails->forwho =  $this->input->post('product_for');
        $productDetails->desc =  $this->input->post('product_desc');
        $productDetails->created =  new DateTime("now");
        ![enter image description here][1]

        $productRepository = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('Entity\Product');
        if($productRepository) echo "found;";
        $createdProduct = $productRepository->createProduct($productDetails);
        echo "Level 2 -> ";

        $p = $productRepository->findBy(array('id' => $createdProduct->id));
        echo "\n" . $p[0]->id. " => " . $p[0]->name;
    }
}
```

Error Message :: Message: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's the exact structure of entity `Product`. But I would ask you to verify if `Product` has some relation to other entities but you maybe passing those entities as String instead of actual entity.

You can use `find` function to get the entity.